# Why my alert can’t execute block and can’t dismiss?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I create an alert with **UIAlertController** and add some action in it. But when I touch button on it and, nothing changed. (Include cancel button) so I can only restart this application can solve this question.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: “my alert”, message: “some message...”, preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: “button1”, style: .default, handler: { (_) in
     print(“button 1 up inside”)
}))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: “button2”, style: .default, handler: { (_) in
     print(“button 2 up inside”)
}))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: “cancel”, style: .cancel, handler: { (_) in

}))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Xcode 10 built.

Comment: I have no idea what mistake I have made, these code are just under a IBAction function. Or might be a bug in Xcode 10?

Comment: @matt it’s so kind of you! But I have not posted the project, maybe I will post them after the first beta version of this project finished. Could you wait for me for several days? thanks!

Comment: If I were you, I would try bit by bit, what happen if you wrap this into a function and the function is called in the "viewDidLoad"

Comment: @Vanya I have tried this, but the alert can’t even appear when I put them in the “viewFidLoad”.

Comment: @matt thanks again! I know the key to my problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks a lot! My view controller can’t close this alert because these code

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

}

override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in an app using the Sprite Kit. Here was the solution:

```
let connectActionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

connectActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Button1", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in

       //Code if this button is pressed
}))

connectActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Button2", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in

       //Code if button2 is pressed
}))

connectActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

let vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
if vc?.presentedViewController == nil {
       vc?.present(connectActionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The last 4 lines were what made it worked. I hope this helps you.

Comment: It’s not the key to my problem. My alert can not execute the code block whose the button I touched. But the alert has appeared.

Comment: In what part of you code is the let action sheet ? Since the code works I think it’s only a matter of where you call it from. Usually those actions sheet or not difficult to implement in an app.

Comment: it’s called in a IBAction function, and this IBAction function has this action sheet only. And I have tried type a test print in this function and, it print successfully. So the IBAction function has no problem to run the code in it. But the test print in the action sheet’s handler: , and it can not print successfully.

Comment: Okay so the action sheet is called correctly but when it’s displayed you lose somehow the connection to the action sheet. What is the class you run this in? Is should probably be a UIViewController for the best results.

Comment: yes, it runs in a UIViewController class, it might be this problem that your said: the connection to the action sheet is lost.

Comment: Something you can try is when you create the class, first thing you do is create var myAlertController = UIAlertController(.....) and add all the buttons here to so that you have access to this alert controller/action sheet anywhere in your code. Then in the IBAction just present the alert with the line self.present(myAlertController...)

Comment: I have tried that, and nothing changed. The problem is still exist.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with an alert poping in the middle of the screen ? This is really weird but their is an answer somehow

Comment: it’s a alert or action sheet , they have the same problem.

Comment: This is really weird, I don’t know what else to try